# XNA multiple rectangle in 1

Tags: c#, xna, rectangles

I'm busy with a 2d top down game in XNA, but i have a problem,

```
if (sourceRect.Intersects(water.waterBlock1) || sourceRect.Intersects(water.waterBlock2))
{
    playerPosition.X -= 1.71f;
}
```

As you can see, i'm checking if the player intersects with the water, and if so, he won't move any further, this all works and all, no problems there, the only problem is, i have 170+ water blocks, and i don't really think it's efficient to make an if statement with 170+ || in your if statement, is there any way to make multiple rectangles into one?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use a `for` loop to check each water block. However, this is quite inefficient. If you witness performance problems, you should consider acceleration structures like bounding box hierarchies. Keep in mind that the loop won't work if you have just 170 variables. You should organize them in an array, list or other structure.

Comment: Another option is using LINQ: `if(allWaterblocks.Any(b => sourceRect.Intersects(b)) { playerPosition.X -= 1.71f; }`.

Comment: I actually made new rectangles that overlay-ed the water blocks which resulted into 25 rectangles, which (seeing how it's a small project) is enough performance wise